# Screen flashing after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 (graphics card NVIDIA GT750M)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, flash, 16.10

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 with no errors, but now I have a flashing screen, with a black desktop; I can only see the task bar and the top ribbon with the time and date. I've followed ALL the instructions here: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics), which means I have tried all the drivers out there (340, 352 - which is the one I should need, 367, 370, 375, 378 and a couple I can't remember), already un/re-installed my gnome desktop environment and am using LightDM as 'default'. I cannot disable the 'Secure Boot' option because I have a Legacy boot by default and cannot switch to UEFI just like that.

What is absolutely bizarre is that I can watch movies locally and videos on YT just fine. More so, I only need to move the mouse and the flashing stops, but if I have the file system open or a simple webpage with nothing moving on it (even the comments section on YT) it returns with a vengeance.

So what is going on and how can I fix it?

Edit 1: Output from `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - done.

Comment: @Pilot6 - any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with a fresh reinstallation of 16.10 but I had the same issue. So I found a copy of 15.10 and installed that one instead. Problem solved. My graphics card now uses the Nouveau display driver and I can see the nvidia 352 in the additional drivers list. WIll just have to upgrade in a year or so...

Comment: Why do you install non-LTS releases. 15.10 is not supported any more. Why not install 16.04 that is supported for 5 years.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Because I spent two days going down the ubuntu rabbit hole and I just didn't feel like experimenting with my machine any more. Plus, there were a lot of people on the web complaining about the same thing happening to them on 16.04; I myself started seeing movies and videos being cut or lagging over the past few weeks, which I realise may or may not be connected. I'll definitely upgrade, but I'm going to wait until the 17.04 distro or until I see the issue with nVidia solved (I intend to check every few months or so). Meanwhile, I'm enjoying my working machine ^^.